# How to store a bounded map inside `StorageValue`?

Tags: weight, boundedvec, map, btreemap, storagevalue

I need to query a specific account id associated with a `Balance` in a pool of 10_000 account ids. But I also need to iterate over all account ids in a reasonable amount of computation time.

So my solution was to use a `BoundedVec` with `binary_search_by_key` with the key of `Balance` wrapped inside a `StorageValue`. This leads to `O(log_n)` time, which is nice.

But couldn't we have a map inside the `StorageValue`, which can query a specific account id in `O(1)` time? I found `BoundedBTreeMap`, but can this be stored inside a `StorageValue`? And if yes, is the result `O(1)` query time? Can the key be an account?

Comment: "But I also need to iterate over all account ids in a reasonable amount of computation time." for what?

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood your question correctly you are asking if you can store a BoundedBTreeMap inside a storage value and what is the complexity of iterating over values in the BTree or getting a single value.

Yes you can store a BoundedBtreeMap inside a StorageValue:

```rust
pub type StorageItemName<T> = StorageValue<_, BoundedBTreeMap<AccountIdOf<T>, BalanceOf<T>, ConstU32<1000>>, OptionQuery>;
```

[ref](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/struct.BoundedBTreeMap.html)

I would recommend using an alias for this.

The complexity of iterating over all elements in a BTree is O(N) as we need to iterate over each element exactly once.

For getting a single value the best case scenario is when the tree is perfectly balanced and is O(log N) (please correct if wrong) tending towards O(N) as the tree becomes less balanced.

Comment: Does this have any advantage over using `BoundedVec` and `binary_search_by_key`? Because you say that `BoundedBTreeMap` has also `O(log_n)` complexity (best case).

Comment: Account id has `Ord` implemented. Is this the reason why the key of the `BoundedBTreeMap` is allowed to be an account id?

Comment: I am asking myself if we have a map that queries a value behind one key in O(1) time.